# mouseEnter and mouseLeave not working in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have written this JavaSccript

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".sidebarmenu").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".sidebarmenu").css('display','block');  
   });
   $(".sidebarmenu").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".sidebarmenu").css('display','enter');
   });
 });
</script>
```

to hide my list in my JSP.

```
<div id="pageNav">
<div class="sidebarmenu">
    <ul>
         <li>......</li>
         <li>......</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Where did I go wrong? The code is not working..

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: on mouseenter of which element you want to hide what

Comment: I want to show "sidebarmenu" on mouseenter

Comment: Were is your JSP.? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/JB5UK/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

     $(".sidebarmenu").mouseenter(function(){

         $(this).find('ul').show('slow');
     });

     $(".sidebarmenu").mouseleave(function(){

         $(this).find('ul').hide('slow');  
     });
 });

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

try adding some text to your div

```
<div class="sidebarmenu">
   my div
    <ul>
         <li>......</li>
         <li>......</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

seems that the `mouseenter` event can not find the target when there are no elements displaying inside the div .

or try adding a border or adding a background color to `sidebarmenu` div

Comment: does this work if I give  $(this).find('#mainmenu').hide('slow'); ?

Comment: @AnushaHoney , now what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(".sidebarmenu").css('display','enter');
```

Do

```
$(".sidebarmenu").css('display','none');
```

Or

```
$(".sidebarmenu").hide();
```

But this code will hide $(".sidebarmenu") so you won't be able to mouseenter after this

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6TV7R/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".sidebarmenu").mouseover(function(){
            alert('over');  
       });
       $(".sidebarmenu").mouseleave(function(){
          alert('leave');  
       });
 });
```

Comment: have you noticed the hiding of "JavaScript" when you mouse over it in the fiddle? I want the reverse of it. div have to be displayed only if I mouse over it.

Comment: as per I dont think it will work....!! coz if you are hiding initially DOM fails to load element ...!!